# django - measuring delay in the middleware

Tags: django

I wrote this code for django 1.8 to compute how long it takes to process a request. I intentionally made the view take 4 seconds but the delta time displayed in this code is 8 milliseconds.
Any ideas how I can measure it in the middleware?

```
from datetime import datetime

class MonitorMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.start = datetime.now()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        print 'Took: ', round((datetime.now() - request.start).microseconds / 1000000.0, 3)
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your time calculations are ok. I have digged into source code for 
[django-request-profiler](https://github.com/yunojuno/django-request-profiler) and compiled a short version of how they implement it.

```
from django.utils import timezone
class ProfilingMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        self.start_ts = timezone.now()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        self.end_ts = timezone.now()
        duration = (self.end_ts - self.start_ts).total_seconds()
        return response
```

I strongly advise you to use open source django profilers out there.

Comment: thanks, it works but sometimes it shows a small number